# access static variable from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 public partial class Page1 :System.Web.UI.Page
 {
      public static LGDP.LDGPSession var1 = null;

      private void Login(this, EventArgs e)
      {
           var1 = new LGDPSession(this, data, data);
      }

      public bool IsLoggedIn()
      {
           bool login = false;

           if (var1 != null)
           {
                login = true;
           }

           return var1;
      }
 }
```

How do I access the Page1 static var1 or function IsLoggedIn() from Page2.apsx ?

```
 public partial class Page2 :System.Web.UI.Page
 {
      Page1.(nothing shows up here)
 }
```

ANSWER ----- created separate class and accessed public var in pageload / postback

```
private static bool _login = false;

public static void SetLoggedIn(object lgdps)
{
    if (lgdps == null)
    {
        _login = false;
    }

    if (lgdps != null)
    {
        _login = true;
    }
}

public static bool IsLogin
{
    get { return _login; }
}
```

Comment: Are both pages in the same namespace?

Comment: To access ISLoggedIn you have create object Page1

Comment: Are you storing (real) session data in static variable? Static variables are shared in the appdomain so everyone will see/use/update/create one LGDPSession which is bad.

Comment: @Oded - yes both pages are in the same namespace.. but it seems aspx pages do not compile together??  Can't acccess one from the other directly (i think).

Comment: @lukas -- can't create object - with or without 'new' variable the class does not appear in intellisense so I think it's not possible.

Comment: Do **NOT** store login data in a static variable! Try logging in using one browser, then navigate to that same app from another browser (or computer) -> you are logged in as that first user! (I know Peter also said this, but it is important enough to repeat:-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create a base class with your functions in it:

```
public class BasePage : Page
{    
      public bool IsLoggedIn()
      {
           bool login = false;

           if (var1 != null)
           {
                login = true;
           }
      }

}
```

And then you can access `IsLoggedIn` from you pages when you inherit from `BasePage`

```
public partial class Page1 : BasePage
{
}

public partial class Page2 : BasePage
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if(IsLoggedIn())
        {
        }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as putting the login and single session variable into a class.cs instead of an aspx.cs page? Right now I am logging in at the aspx.cs page level to maintain a top level hierarchy from within my web application... I would like to continue to be able to do this but know from another aspx.cs page whether or not the first page is logged in or not... (I only want to maintain one login session at all times).

Comment: @Erwin... trying answer from this question.. but it's not working... yet   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445155/can-i-access-viewstate-of-one-page-in-another-page-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: you were right.. Messing with ViewState or Current.Item.Add etc  is too much hassle.. and does not work I created a separate class.. ! (Why didn't I think of that???) showing class above....

Answer (score 3):

Your function `IsLoggedIn` in `Page1` doesn't compile. It has to return something:

```
public bool IsLoggedIn()
{
  bool login = false;

  if (var1 != null)
  {
    login = true;
  }

  return login;
}
```

Or simply:

```
public bool IsLoggedIn()
{
  return var1 != null;
}
```

Once the page compiles, its members should show up in the intellisense.